# OpenGL: Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) when running

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault, glfw

I am writing a game engine in C++ and OpenGL and when I open my first test window i receive this issue:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

There is no error when compiling, and it compiles just fine. The problem lies when I go to open the window.

HOW TO REPRODUCE:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

int main()
{
  typedef void (*GL_GENBUFFERS) (GLsizei, GLuint*);
  GL_GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers = (GL_GENBUFFERS) glfwGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");
  unsigned int buffer;
  glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);

  glfwInit();
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "BloodBunny", NULL, NULL);
  if (window == NULL)
  {
    std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
  }
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
  if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
  {
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }
  while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
  {
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
  }
  glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
  glViewport(0,0,800,600);
  glfwTerminate();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger or add prints to find out where it crashed (or look at the core)

Comment: Apparently, there is no core. this is the ls for my folder: glad.c  main.cpp  main.exe

Comment: Depending on the OS you may have to set limits or various other things to enable and locate cores.

Comment: `glfwGetProcAddress` returns `NULL` on error. It's worth checking (I consider it mandatory because an error not checked will be a bug sooner or later) before using the returned value. General recommendation: Don't ignore the return codes. if the programmer didn't think the value they returned was important, they wouldn't have wasted their, or the computer's, time returning it.

Comment: Time spent learning how to step through a program with a debugger will be repaid a thousandfold. At a conservative estimate.

Comment: It returned zero, so that's probably an okay piece of code.

Comment: So I ran it through a debugger, I got nothing in return (used gdb)

Comment: if `glfwGetProcAddress` returned 0, that's a `NULL`. The call failed. You can [get more information on why with `glfwGetError`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/intro_guide.html#error_handling). If `glfwGetProcAddress` isn't the *it* that retuned 0 ignore me and specify what the *it* is.

Comment: Don't run through a debugger, step. Examine what happens at each line. If the program does something you don't expect like store the wrong value or take the wrong path, stop and figure out why. You probably found a bug.

Comment: the glfwGetProcAddress did return zero, I will look into that webpage further. Thank you!

Comment: Tactical note: A function needs to be declared before first use, but a definition of the function also counts as a declaration. You can remove `void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);`

Comment: Here's a question: I'm running this on Pop!_OS 21.10. I know that glfwGetProcAdrdress is OS-specific, so am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What was the error reported? For example, was it  GLFW_NO_CURRENT_CONTEXT?

Comment: how can I check?

Comment: `glfwGetError` as described above by user4581301

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm new to OpenGL. glfwGetError is telling me I need a char in the argument, this is what i put in:   std::cout << glfwGetError(glfwGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers")) << std::endl;

Comment: Use it as described at the link given by user4581301: `int code = glfwGetError(NULL);` then compare it with the error codes you googled in the documentation at https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__errors.html

Comment: Why are you trying to get & call `glGenBuffers()` before `glfwMakeContextCurrent()`?  `glfwGetProcAddress()` will never return anything useful without a current [GL context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context).

Comment: you're right, i did fix that and i still got the same error tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glfwGetProcAddress()` will only (potentially, depending on the name requested and the GL version of the current context) return usable, non-`NULL` function-pointers if a GL context is current.

With GLFW you make a window's context current via `glfwMakeContextCurrent()` so if you truly want to grab your own pointer to `glGenBuffers()` you need to move the `glfwGetProcAddress()` call to *after* a successful `glfwMakeContextCurrent()`:

```
...
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
...
typedef void (*GL_GENBUFFERS) (GLsizei, GLuint*);
GL_GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers = (GL_GENBUFFERS) glfwGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");
unsigned int buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
...
```

...though honestly there's little point since you're calling `gladLoadGLLoader()` right after `glfwMakeContextCurrent()`  which will populate a perfectly usable `glGenBuffers()` pointer at global scope all on its own.

Comment: @RyanTripleSeven: And thank _you_ for a revision-1 [mcve]!  Those are always super-helpful :)